# how to use neural networks for new data?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I coded some of the neural networks like image classifier,mnist and NLP I
got an accuracy of 98 percent on my GPU (NVIDIA GT 610). How can I feed new data (not training data) to my neural network and get the predictions?

Let's suppose:

```
  Inputs    Output
  0     0    1     0
  1     1    1     1
  1     0    1     1
  0     1    1     0
```

I got an accuracy of 98.7 how to give an input like [ 1 1 0] and predict the output. Is there any method in Tensorflow to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your output variable is `y` and your input placeholder is `x`:

```
sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images})
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

Comment: If I want to include my own 28x28 image can i specify the x value in feed_dict as the path of my image? @Martin Thoma

Comment: Not as the path, but as a numpy array. Just have a look at the format of `mnist.test.images` ... or whatever you currently put into your network to train / evaluate it.

Comment: Thank you @martin Thoma and another question is it good to implement neural network without any framework using c++ or use some like tensorflow or keras for image classification?

Comment: What does "good" mean? Why would you not use Tensorflow / Keras? I mean, you could always also do it in Assembly. Or [use butterflies like real programmers](https://xkcd.com/378/).